# Source for physical instructions to pronounce Danish vowels and consonants?

Tags: pronunciation, danish

I am trying to learn Danish, and I cannot find any instructions on the physical movements necessary to make Danish vowels and consonants. I can find plenty of sources that say this or that letter sounds like such-and-such, but not how to make the sounds.

When I learned Spanish in high school many years ago, the teacher spent a considerable amount of time teaching us where to place our tongue and what to do with our lips in making the sounds of Spanish (for example, place the tip of the tongue between the teeth and the alveolar ridge for a 'd', don't close the lips all the way to make a 'b', etc.), and it helped a great deal, especially since we were learning Spanish in a part of the U.S. where pronunciations varied significantly from those where the publishing houses were located (New York, Chicago, etc.). I would really like to find information like that.